# Prevent knockout from redrawing initial state

Tags: knockout.js

I'm finishing up a single-page web app using knockout js.

Many of the pages are accessible directly (using pushstate internally to handle navigation and all that) and I will be having identical content constructed by the server so that those pages come pre-populated.

Although not mission-critical, it would be nice for knockout to not redraw the page when it is bound to the data for whatever page the user enters on, but still be interactive when the observables were updated in the future.

For example, I might have a list in a knockout view in the landing page:

```
//empty on landing page load
view.items = ko.observableArray();

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
</ul>
```

And then later the user clicks on "Fruits" link somewhere, and items is updated via ajax:

```
view.items(["apple", "banana", "orange"]);
```

Pretty standard usage so far.

But what if the user comes directly to the "Fruits" page? Currently, I have the `view.items` array populated on page load, which works. But now I also want the correct HTML to be delivered by the server. So the "Fruits" page not only sets the initial `view.items`, but pre-renders that list:

```
//pre-set items list observable
view.items = ko.observableArray(["apple", "banana", "orange"]);

//server-side pre-rendered items list
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text:$data">apple</li>
    <li data-bind="text:$data">banana</li>
    <li data-bind="text:$data">orange</li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to avoid is knockout redrawing the list on page load, but I need to keep the list bound since the `view.items` array might be changed at any time.

I am hoping there is something built-in I'm missing in the docs. An authoritative "this is not trivial" answer is welcome if that be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` binding uses the contents of its bound element as a `template`. This results in 9 fruits being rendered if you were to go with your current approach.

I'd suggest using the `template` binding instead. This way, the *initial* content is just a placeholder. When the bindings get applied, it is removed from the DOM.

The `template` you link contains the list item for just one fruit. \

Here's an example that binds the UI after 2 seconds. As you can see, there's no noticeable UI change when knockout replaces the contents of the list.

```js
setTimeout(
  function() {
    ko.applyBindings({ items: [ "banana", "apple", "orange" ] });
  },
  2000
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 't-fruit-li', foreach: items }">
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
</ul>

<p data-bind="visible: false">Waiting for apply bindings...</p>

<script id="t-fruit-li" type="text/html">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</script>
```